# How to fix App crashes when initializing Translate using google translate API

Tags: java, android, api, translate

I'm writing a basic translator app using the google translate API, but the app crashes when I click the button and it reaches the Translate  translates initialize, I've tried a few different solutions but can't seem to find a solution that works.
This is my first time posting here, i believe what I posted below is the crash log.

```
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translation;
...
public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("translatecheck", "I clicked a button");
            String[] isoArr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.iso);
            Log.d("translatecheck", "isoarr created");
            TextView textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
            Log.d("translatecheck", "textElement initialized");
            //This is where the app cashes
            //Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
            Translate translate = createTranslateService();

            Log.d("translatecheck", "translate service created");
            String sourceLang = "en";
            String targetLang = isoArr[pos];
            TranslateOption srcLang = TranslateOption.sourceLanguage(sourceLang);
            TranslateOption tgtLang = TranslateOption.targetLanguage(targetLang);
            Log.d("translatecheck", "translate service initialized");
            // The text to translate
            editText = findViewById(R.id.edit);
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            Log.d("translatecheck", "converted edit text to string");
            //Translates some text into spinner language
            Translation translation = translate.translate(text, srcLang, tgtLang);
            /*Translation translation =
                    translate.translate(
                            text,
                            TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
                            TranslateOption.targetLanguage(isoArr[pos]));
            */

            Log.d("translatecheck", "we have translated");

            //textElement.setText(translation.toString()); //leave this line to assign a specific text
            textElement.setText(translation.getTranslatedText());

        }
...
public static Translate createTranslateService() {
        return TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
}
```

Crash log:

```
04-09 01:00:59.442 4076-4076/com.example.translate01 I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
04-09 01:00:59.455 4076-4076/com.example.translate01 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-09 01:00:59.456 4076-4076/com.example.translate01 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.translate01, PID: 4076
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:358)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:331)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:249)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:142)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1040)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getAppEngineProjectIdFromMetadataServer(ServiceOptions.java:460)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getAppEngineProjectId(ServiceOptions.java:429)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId(ServiceOptions.java:336)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getDefaultProject(ServiceOptions.java:313)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:264)
        at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions.<init>(TranslateOptions.java:143)
        at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions.<init>(TranslateOptions.java:39)
        at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions$Builder.build(TranslateOptions.java:138)
        at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance(TranslateOptions.java:261)
        at com.example.translate01.MainActivity.createTranslateService(MainActivity.java:96)
        at com.example.translate01.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5209)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21247)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5428)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete [stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: share your crash log. you probably forgot to add the INTERNET permission in the manifest.

Comment: Kindly update your question with stack trace when you build/run the app. The answer would be hidden in the trace itself.

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit to format the post to update it, lmk if there is anything else I can do.

Comment: I already have the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  permission in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You are having a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException), which means you are running internet related tasks on the main thread.

You can't run internet related tasks on Android Main thread (as for why, see [Keeping your app responsive](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr)).

Just move whichever translate operation that does internet tasks (presumably `translate.translate()`) into a new Thread, Async task, or whatever structure you prefer, and listen for the callback for the result.